# I Can't find SDK in LIBGDX

Tags: libgdx

I recently downloaded the android studio and i'm trying to set up the libgdx. When I go to create a project I keep getting the error
 " Your android SDK path doesn't contain an SDK! Please instal the Android SDK, including all platforms and build tools!"

So my next step is...I go into android studio and under tools I go to, locate the SDK. Android Studios is telling me where it is, but then when I go back to the LIBGDX to locate the exact location it isn't there. 
I'm on a mac and the exact location is.... /Users/myname/Library/Android/sdk

and then I come to find out that when I go in manually through my MAC the 'Library' part is greyed out...

I'm wondering if there's a solution to this, or how I can resolve this

Comment: You can specify SDK by adding a top-level `local.properties` file with the property `sdk.dir=/Users/myname/Library/Android/sdk`.

Comment: I have this problem as well. I spend about 6 hours trying to find the solution, found it and used it successfully, then accidentally replaced it with where I wanted my destination to be. I've fixed bricked phones in computers in less time. Good luck.